# Min Priority Queue and Max Priority Queue not sorting correctly

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am coding a Min Priority Queue and a Max Priority Queue like the following:

```
PriorityQueue<Double> max_pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Double>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
                if(o1<o2) return +1;
                if(o1.equals(o2)) return 0;
                return -1;
            }
        });

        PriorityQueue<Double> min_pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Double>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
                if(o1>o2) return +1;
                if(o1.equals(o2)) return 0;
                return -1;
            }
        });
```

Numbers of an input array are added one by one to the queue. However, when the array [12,4,5,3,8,7] is a sample input and the output of printing the priority queues is:

> MIN: [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 12.0, 8.0, 7.0]
> MAX: [12.0, 8.0, 7.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

Is there something wrong with the comparator I defined? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate over the elements of a `PriorityQueue` those elements are not *completely* ordered. The only thing you can be sure of is that a `PriorityQueue` will enforce that the **smallest** and **biggest** elements are the **first** elements of the `min_pq` and `max_pq` priority queues, respectively.

From the [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) javadocs:

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the
> specified ordering.

Based on that assumption you can print in order if you use the method `poll()`:

```
while(!max_pq.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println(max_pq.poll());
}
```

The poll method:

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this
> queue is empty.

For comparing `Double`s you should use the method  `Double.compare(o1, o2)`. Moreover, you can simplify your comparators using  lambda and method references, namely instead of :

```
PriorityQueue<Double> max_pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Double>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
                if(o1<o2) return +1;
                if(o1.equals(o2)) return 0;
                return -1;
            }
        });

        PriorityQueue<Double> min_pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Double>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
                if(o1>o2) return +1;
                if(o1.equals(o2)) return 0;
                return -1;
            }
        });
```

you can use the more elegant and simple:

```
PriorityQueue<Double> max_pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Double::compareTo);
PriorityQueue<Double> min_pq = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o2, o1));
```

Alternatively, instead of `PriorityQueue`, you could opt for a `TreeSet`, and there you can iterate over the elements in the order based on the comparator that you have chosen, without having to remove any element.

```
TreeSet<Double> max_pq = new TreeSet<>(Double::compareTo);
```

Another benefit of the `TreeSet` is that it comes with the method `descendingSet()`. Therefore, you do not need to keep two data structures to keep both the `min` and `max` order, instead you can have just:

```
  TreeSet<Double> max_pq = new TreeSet<>(Double::compareTo);
   
  max_pq.forEach(System.out::println);
  max_pq.descendingSet().forEach(System.out::println);
```